# Getting 404 error while trying to submit data to database in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm working on a forum using Express/React and I'm having trouble submitting/pushing the data from the form to the database. For now I'm just trying to add topic titles to its own MongoDB collection but in the future I plan on adding more message content. I have no idea why it's not working. I have another similar form for registering account and it's working just fine. I think it may have to do with `useDispatch` in my `submitHandler` and that I mistakenly did something wrong because when I `console.log(title)` it shows the `title` just fine so I know I'm getting the data but I'm stuck with getting that data to save to the database after debugging for several hours.

This is the error code I'm getting when I hit submit.

`POST http://localhost:3000/topic/create 404 (Not Found)`

Here's my `forumApiSlice`

```
const TOPIC_URL = "/topic";
export const forumApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    create: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `${TOPIC_URL}/create`,
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

And here is my form code.

```
const CreateTopic = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [create] = useCreateMutation(); // forumApiSlice

  const { userInfo } = useSelector((state) => state.auth); // to get the author of the topic

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await create({ title, author }).unwrap();
      dispatch({ ...res });
      navigate("/");
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(err.error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <h1>Create Topic</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group className="my-2" controlId="title">
          <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Title"
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="my-2" controlId="author">
          <Form.Label></Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            value={userInfo.name}
            onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button type="submit" variant="primary" className="mt-3">
          Create Topic
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think you didn't specified http method to be "POST"

Comment: 404 means the page doesn't exist - are you sure your api endpoint is correct